# Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, array-of-dict

Given an array of objects :

```
people = [
    {id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age:"15" },
    {id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age:"25" },
    {id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age:"5" },
    {id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age:"35" },
    {id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age:"41" },
    {id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age:" 30" },
    {id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age:" 31" },
    {id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age:" 78" },
]
```

And an array of wanted ids:

```
id_filter = [1,4,5,8]
```

How to filter array `people` to return the target ids defined in `id_filter` and of `gender=m` ?

Comment: Please use either `const` or `let` to declare variables, for example `const people = []`.

Answer (score 95):

The simplest way to filter is to use the array's [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, similar to this:

```
people.filter(person => id_filter.includes(person.id))
```

Comment: what if i want to add another condition that gender should be == m ?

Comment: `people.filter((person) => person.gender == 'm')`

Comment: It would really be `people.filter((person) => id_filter.includes(Number(person.id)) && person.gender === "m")` or `people.filter(({ id, gender }) => id_filter.includes(Number(id)) && gender === "m")`.

Answer (score 25):

You can use **[`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** with few conditions to get the output you want. Also i have corrected your JSON.

```
var filtered = people.filter(function(item) {
        return id_filter.indexOf(item.id) !== -1 && item.gender==='m';
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var  people =[
  { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "gender": "m","age": "15" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "a", "gender": "m", "age": "25"  },
  { "id": 3,"name": "efg", "gender": "f","age": "5" },
  { "id": 4,"name": "hjk","gender": "m","age": "35" },
  {  "id": 5, "name": "ikly","gender": "m","age": "41" },
  { "id": 6, "name": "ert", "gender": "f", "age": "30" },
  { "id": 7, "name": "qwe", "gender": "f", "age": "31" },
  { "id":8, "name": "bdd",  "gender": "m", "age": " 8" }
];
var id_filter = [1,4,5,8];
var filtered = people.filter(function(item) {
    return id_filter.indexOf(item.id) !== -1 && item.gender==='m';
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 11):

With `Array.includes()` function:

```js
var people = [
    {id : "1", name : "abc", gender : "m", age :"15" }, {id : "2", name : "a", gender : "m", age :"25" },
    {id : "3", name : "efg", gender : "f", age :"5" },  {id : "4", name : "hjk", gender : "m", age :"35" },
    {id : "5", name : "ikly", gender : "m", age :"41" }, {id : "6", name : "ert", gender : "f", age :" 30" },
    {id : "7", name : "qwe", gender : "f", age :" 31" }, {id : "8", name : "bdd", gender : "m", age :" 78" }
], 
    id_filter = [1,4,5,8],
    result = people.filter((o) => id_filter.includes(+o.id) && o.gender == "m");       
 
console.log(result);
```

---

- `+o.id` - `+` is used here to cast a numeric string into number

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that by the following code:

```
const filtered_people = people.filter(function(person){
    return id_filter.includes(person.id) && person.gender === 'm';
});
```

Just make sure the id for each person is an integer and not an string, as in your example. Otherwise, the includes() function won't match. Also, your `people` array has internal syntax problems. So, the final code would look like this:

```js
const people = [
    {id: 1, name: "abc", gender: "m", age:15},
    {id: 2, name: "a", gender: "m", age: 25},
    {id: 3, name: "efg", gender: "f", age: 5},
    {id: 4, name: "hjk", gender: "f", age: 35},
    {id: 5, name: "ikly", gender: "m", age: 41},
    {id: 6, name: "ert", gender: "f", age: 30},
    {id: 7, name: "qwe", gender: "f", age: 31},
    {id: 8, name: "bdd", gender: "m", age: 78}
]
const id_filter = [1,4,5,8]
const filtered_people = people.filter((person) => id_filter.includes(person.id) && person.gender === 'm')
console.log(filtered_people)
```

I hope this helps you.
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For this case you can make use of filter and include function, since you id's are string,it need to be parse before use.

```
var result = people.filter((person) => (id_filter.includes(parseInt(person.id)) && person.gender ==='m'))
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case it makes more sense to do this by foot 
so first you need to iterate through your `people` array
then you check if a persons id is equal to your filter list

```
for(person in people) {
     for(id in id_filter) {
         if(person[id] == id && person[gender] == "m"){

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I want a filtered array and also the ids are not in serial. also another condition needs to be added that gender is = m

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` like:

```js
function filter(arr, ids, gender) {                              // takes an array of people arr, an array of indexes ids, and a gender and return the matched people objects from arr
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {                              // filtering each object...
    return ids.includes(obj.id) && obj.gender === gender;        // if this object is is included in the ids array and if its gender property is equal to the desired gender
  });
}

var people = [{id:"1",name:"abc",gender:"m",age:"15"},{id:"2",name:"a",gender:"m",age:"25"},{id:"3",name:"efg",gender:"f",age:"5"},{id:"4",name:"hjk",gender:"m",age:"35"},{id:"5",name:"ikly",gender:"m",age:"41"},{id:"6",name:"ert",gender:"f",age:"30"},{id:"7",name:"qwe",gender:"f",age:"31"},{id:"8",name:"bdd",gender:"m",age:"78"}];

console.log(filter(people, ["5", "7", "4"], "m"));               // filtering elements where id is one of ["5", "7", "4"] and the gender is "m".
```

**Note:** The `id` property of the objects in `people` are strings so you have to either provides an array of string ids to `filter` or convert the `id` property to a number before passing it to `includes`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `id_filter` is large, you would want to first convert it to a [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). This will allow for constant-time lookup. You can then iterate your `people` array using `.filter()` and return `true` if your set [`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the `id` in it and if the gender is equal to `'m'`.

```js
const people = [ {id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age:"15" }, {id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age:"25" }, {id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age:"5" }, {id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age:"35" }, {id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age:"41" }, {id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age:" 30" }, {id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age:" 31" }, {id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age:" 78" }, ];

const id_filter = new Set([1,4,5,8]);
const res = people.filter(({id, gender}) => id_filter.has(+id) && gender === 'm');
console.log(res);
```

Overall, the time complexity for this approach will be `O(N + k)` as opposed to the `O(Nk)` you would get if you were using the `.includes()` or `.indexOf()` approach, where `N` is the length of the `people` array, and `k` is the length of the `id_filter` array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const people = [
    {id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age: "15" },
    {id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age: "25" },
    {id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age: "5" },
    {id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age: "35" },
    {id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age: "41" },
    {id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age: " 30" },
    {id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age: " 31" },
    {id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age: " 78" },
]

const idFilter = [1,4,5,8]

const idIsInList = id => idFilter.includes(+id) // "+id" to make sure it is a number, not a string
const genderIsMale = gender => gender === "m"
const result = people.filter(item => idIsInList(item.id) && genderIsMale(item.gender))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    people = [
        {id : "1", name : "abc", gender : "m", age :"15" },
        {id : "2", name : "a", gender : "m", age :"25" },
        {id : "3", name : "efg", gender : "f", age :"5" },
        {id : "4", name : "hjk", gender : "m", age :"35" },
        {id : "5", name : "ikly", gender : "m", age :"41" },
        {id : "6", name : "ert", gender : "f", age :" 30" },
        {id : "7", name : "qwe", gender : "f", age :" 31" },
        {id : "8", name : "bdd", gender : "m", age :" 78" }
    ]
    var id_filter = ["1","4","5","8"], filteredPeople = []; 
    for( var i=people.length-1; i>=0; --i){ 
      if( id_filter.indexOf( people[i].id ) != -1 ){ 
        filteredPeople.push( people[i] ); 
      } 
    }
    console.log( filteredPeople );
```