# filtering an array of objects based on another array containing keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array of Objects as shown below:

```
people = [
{id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age:"15" },
{id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age:"25" },
{id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age:"5" },
{id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age:"35" },
{id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age:"41" },
{id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age:" 30" },
{id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age:" 31" },
{id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age:" 78" },
 ]
```

And I have another array containing the values I want from the object:

```
filter = ['name','age']
```

I want to filter the array of people to return an array of objects that contains only values in that filter. So the Output should look like this:

```
    people = [
{ name: "abc",  age:"15" },
{ name: "a", age:"25" },
{ name: "efg",  age:"5" },
{ name: "hjk",  age:"35" },
{ name: "ikly",  age:"41" },
{ name: "ert",  age:" 30" },
{ name: "qwe",  age:" 31" },
{ name: "bdd", age:" 78" },
 ]
```

This is similar to the question here: [filtering an array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filtering-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Use map method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the object and take the keys for new entries.

```js
var people = [{ id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age: "15" }, { id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age: "25" }, { id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age: "5" }, { id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age: "35" }, { id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age: "41" }, { id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age: " 30" }, { id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age: " 31" }, { id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age: " 78" }],
    keys = ['name', 'age'],
    result = people.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `map` with `reduce`:

```
const result = people.map(item => filter.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = item[cur];
  return acc;
}, {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create `entries` by `Object.entries`, then filter our object by `filter` array using `filter` method and then just `map` desired elements which can be created by `Object.fromEntries`:

```
people = people.map(s => ({ ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(s)
    .filter(([k, v]) => filter.some(f => f == k)))}));
```

```js
let people = [
    {id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age:"15" },
    {id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age:"25" },
    {id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age:"5" },
    {id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age:"35" },
    {id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age:"41" },
    {id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age:" 30" },
    {id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age:" 31" },
    {id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age:" 78" },
];

let filter = ['name','age'];
people = people.map(s => ({ ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(s)
    .filter(([k, v]) => filter.some(f => f ==k)))}));

console.log(people);
```

Answer (score -1):

Map method can resolve your issue.

```js
const people = [
{id: "1", name: "abc", gender: "m", age:"15" },
{id: "2", name: "a", gender: "m", age:"25" },
{id: "3", name: "efg", gender: "f", age:"5" },
{id: "4", name: "hjk", gender: "m", age:"35" },
{id: "5", name: "ikly", gender: "m", age:"41" },
{id: "6", name: "ert", gender: "f", age:" 30" },
{id: "7", name: "qwe", gender: "f", age:" 31" },
{id: "8", name: "bdd", gender: "m", age:" 78" },
 ];
 
 const result = people.map(person => {
    return {
        name: person.name,
        age: person.age
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You haven't used the filter array

Comment: Why to use filter array?

Comment: Because it says so in the OP

Comment: Nina changed the name of the `filter` array to `keys`. She did use the dynamic filtering the OP asker wants. You did a hard coded mapping. That's why your answer is not correct