# Subset array of object based on keys from another array(not static) and then filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, underscore.js

I have an array of object which needs to be filtered based upon the certain value :

```js
let data = 
[
  {
    "region": 28,
    "nuts": 33,
    "score" : 26
   }, 
  {
    "region": 18,
    "nuts": 22,
    "score" : 21
   }
]
```

The other array includes keys for which the above object is to be filtered and also subsetted :

```js
// this changes everytime 
// it may include ALL the keys or only ONE key of above object 
let keysArray = ["region", "score"]
(OR )
let keysArray = ["region", "nuts"]
```

Now if the `data` needs to be filtered for `region` and `score` above 25 then it should return the following :

```js
// when => keysArray = ["region", "score"]
// region && score >= 25 
// expected output
 [
  {
    "region": 28,
    "score" : 26
   }
 ]

// when => keysArray = ["region", "nuts"]
// region &&  nuts >= 25 
// expected output
 [
  {
    "region": 28,
    "nuts" : 33
   }
 ]
```

How can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

PS : This does not answer the question -
[filtering an array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filtering-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can filter and subset when `keysArray` is static. But it is dynamic and I am not able to find the solution around it. I used `filter`function for filtering and also some other methods like `_pick`from lodash to subset.

Comment: No it does not. In my case the parent array of object `data` is to be scanned and subset for its keys within `keysArray`. And this `keysArray`changes every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Underscore (or Lodash), you can write much shorter code.

```
// The function that will do the trick.
function subsetFilter(data, keys, predicate) {
    return _.chain(data)
        .map(_.partial(_.pick, _, keys))
        .filter(_.partial(_.every, _, predicate))
        .value();
}

// Usage.
subsetFilter(data, ['region', 'nuts'], x => x >= 25);
```

Let's break this into pieces.

```
function subsetFilter(data, keys, predicate) {
```

We create a function with three parameters: the data to be subsetted and filtered, the array of keys that may be variable, and the `predicate`, which can be any function that returns a boolean. For example, I used `x => x >= 25` above to state that the properties should be greater than or equal to 25.

```
_.chain(data)
```

We wrap the data in a special wrapper object which will allow us to chain multiple Underscore functions, each processing the result of the previous function in the chain ([doc](https://underscorejs.org/#chaining)).

```
_.pick
```

This is a function that takes two arguments: an object and an array of keys. It returns a copy of the object with only the properties of which the names were listed in the array of keys ([doc](https://underscorejs.org/#pick)). For example:

```
_.pick({a: 1, b: 2}, ['a', 'c']) // returns {a: 1}
```

Next,

```
_.partial(_.pick, _, keys)
```

This transforms `_.pick` into a new function, where the second argument has already been pre-filled with `keys`. The `_` signifies that this modified version of `_.pick` is still looking for its first argument ([doc](https://underscorejs.org/#partial)). It is equivalent to the following function:

```
function(obj) {
    return _.pick(obj, keys);
}
```

Completing this line,

```
.map(_.partial(_.pick, _, keys))
```

We call [`_.map`](https://underscorejs.org/#map) on the chained `data` wrapper, producing a new array in which each element has been transformed through the function we created using `_.partial` and `_.pick`. In our example, the chain wrapper contains the following data at this point:

```
[
  {
    "region": 28,
    "nuts": 33
   }, 
  {
    "region": 18,
    "nuts": 22
   }
]
```

(so basically still the same data, except that the `score` properties are no longer there because we didn't `_.pick` them.)

```
_.partial(_.every, _, predicate)
```

Again, we use `_.partial` to create a modified version of a function where the second argument has already been pre-filled. This time, the base function is [`_.every`](https://underscorejs.org/#every), which takes an array or object and a predicate. It returns `true` if the predicate returns `true` for each element of the array or each property of the object, otherwise `false`. The pre-filled second argument is the `predicate` parameter of our `subsetFilter` function. Basically we are stating the following here: give this function an object, and it will tell you whether all of its properties meet `predicate`.

```
.filter(_.partial(_.every, _, predicate))
```

We [`_.filter`](https://underscorejs.org/#filter) the intermediate result in our chain with the function we just created using `_.partial` and `_.every`. We keep only the objects in the array of which each property meets `predicate`. At this point, our chain wrapper contains the following value:

```
[
  {
    "region": 28,
    "nuts": 33
   }
]
```

which is the result you want, but it is still wrapped. So as a final step, we remove the wrapper ([doc](https://underscorejs.org/#value)):

```
.value();
```

This is the end of our expression and the result that we return from our function.

Answer (score 1):

I created a working snippet.

```js
let data = [{
    region: 28,
    nuts: 33,
    score: 26
  },
  {
    region: 18,
    nuts: 22,
    score: 21
  }
];

// this changes everytime
// it may include ALL the keys or only ONE key of above object
let keysArray = ["region", "score"];

// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;

const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");

filterData(keysArray, 25).forEach(item => {
  resultDiv.innerHTML += `<li>region: ${item.region}, score: ${
    item.score
  }</li>`;
});

function filterData(keys, val) {
  let result = [];

  data.forEach(dataItem => {
    let isEligible = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      let key = keys[i];
      isEligible = dataItem[key] >= val;
      if (!isEligible) break;
    }

    if (isEligible) result.push(dataItem);
  });

  return result;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Working demo in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-swutjy?embed=1&file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = 
[
  {
    "region": 28,
    "nuts": 33,
    "score" : 26
   }, 
  {
    "region": 18,
    "nuts": 22,
    "score" : 21
   }
];

let keysArray = ["region", "nuts"];

const hasValAboveThreshold = (item, threshold) => {
  return keysArray.every((key) => item[key] > threshold);
}

const getItem = (item) => {
  return keysArray.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = item[key];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const output = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (hasValAboveThreshold(val, 25)) {
    acc.push(getItem(val));
  }  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This works like a charm. It would be great if you could also add a little bit of explanation to the code. Thanks