# Java Script filter nested object properties by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested-object

I need to filter nested Objects by property values. I know similar questions have been asked before, but I couldn't find a solution for a case where the values were stored in an array.

In the provided code sample, I will need to filter the object based on tags. I would like to get objects which include "a" and "b" in the tags array.

```js
const input1 = {
    "0":{
        "id":"01",
        "name":"item_01",
        "tags":["a","b"],
    },
    "1":{
        "id":"02",
        "name":"item_02",
        "tags":["a","c","d"],
    },
    "2":{
        "id":"03",
        "name":"item_03",
        "tags":["a","b","f"],
    }
}
 
function search(input, key) {
   return Object.values(input).filter(({ tags }) => tags === key);
}

console.log(search(input1, "a"));
```

As an output, I would like to receive the fallowing:

```
{
    "0":{
        "id":"01",
        "name":"item_01",
        "tags":["a","b"],
    },
    "2":{
        "id":"03",
        "name":"item_03",
        "tags":["a","b","f"],
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep the object structure, you should use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.values` and to revert back to object type use `Object.fromEntries`:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input).filter(...))
```

To make it work for multiple keys, use `every` in combination with `includes` as predicate:

```
keys.every(key => tags.includes(key))
```

```js
const input1 = {
    "0":{
        "id":"01",
        "name":"item_01",
        "tags":["a","b"],
    },
    "1":{
        "id":"02",
        "name":"item_02",
        "tags":["a","c","d"],
    },
    "2":{
        "id":"03",
        "name":"item_03",
        "tags":["a","b","f"],
    }
}
 
function search(input, keys) {
   return Object.fromEntries(
   Object.entries(input).filter(([, { tags }]) => keys.every(key => tags.includes(key)))
   )
   
}

console.log(search(input1, ["a", "b"]));
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
function search(input, key) {
  Object.values(input).filter(x=>x.tags.includes(key))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the `[key, value]` pair as an array of an array then you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#:%7E:text=filter()%20calls%20a%20provided,value%20that%20coerces%20to%20true%20.) to filter out the elements that don't contain the element in the `key` array. Finally, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to produce a single value i.e object as a final result

```js
const input1 = {
  "0": {
    id: "01",
    name: "item_01",
    tags: ["a", "b"],
  },
  "1": {
    id: "02",
    name: "item_02",
    tags: ["a", "c", "d"],
  },
  "2": {
    id: "03",
    name: "item_03",
    tags: ["a", "b", "f"],
  },
};

function search(input, key) {
  return Object.entries(input)
    .filter(([, v]) => key.every((ks) => v.tags.includes(ks)))
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
      acc[k] = v;
      return acc;
    }, {});
}

console.log(search(input1, ["a", "b"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function search(input, tagsToFind) {
  return Object.values(input).filter(inputItem => {
    tagsToFind = Array.isArray(tagsToFind) ? tagsToFind : [tagsToFind];
    let tagFound = false;
    for (const key in tagsToFind) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(tagsToFind, key)) {
        const element = tagsToFind[key];
        if (inputItem.tags.indexOf(element) === -1) {
          tagFound = false;
          break;
        } else {
          tagFound = true;
        }
      }
    }

    return tagFound;
  })

  // ({ tags }) => tags === key);
}
```

}