# Get Object From Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need the whole array of objects using an array of ids. I need to match it using `contact_id`. You may see expected output below

**Array of objects (contacts)**

```
[
    {
        "contact_id": 1,
        "f_name": "Hello",
    },
    {
        "contact_id": 2,
        "f_name": "YA",
    },
     {
        "contact_id": 3,
        "f_name": "Minion",
    },
     {
        "contact_id": 4,
        "f_name": "HALU",
    },
]
```

**Array of ids (contacts2)**

```
{
    "contact_ids": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ],
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "contact_id": 1,
        "f_name": "Hello",
    },
    {
        "contact_id": 2,
        "f_name": "YA",
    },
]
```

**Code**

```
contacts.filter(item = > item.contact_id === contacts2)
```

Comment: you can use includes in your filter: [Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46894352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
contacts.filter(item => contacts2.contact_ids.some(id => id == item.contact_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `contact_ids` array to return a `{ contact_id: number, f_name: string }` object for each one
- Inside the mapping function use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to find the first contact that gets matched
- Make sure to either use `==` instead of `===` or convert the string to a number before doing the check, since using `===` with a string and a number will always return `false`

```js
var contacts = [{ "contact_id": 1, "f_name": "Hello" }, { "contact_id": 2, "f_name": "YA" }, { "contact_id": 3, "f_name": "Minion" }, { "contact_id": 4, "f_name": "HALU" }];

var contacts2 = { "contact_ids": [ "1", "2" ] };

var result = contacts2.contact_ids.map(function(id) {
  return contacts.find(function(contact) {
    // make sure to use `==` instead of `===` since you're comparing a string to a number
    return contact.contact_id == id;
  });
});
// You could also chain `.filter(Boolean)` if you wanted to discard the contacts that weren't found
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [{
    "contact_id": 1,
    "f_name": "Hello",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 2,
    "f_name": "YA",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 3,
    "f_name": "Minion",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 4,
    "f_name": "HALU",
  },
];

const ids = {
  "contact_ids": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
};

const filteredItems = items.filter(item => ids.contact_ids.includes(item.contact_id.toString()));

console.log(filteredItems)
```

Comment: How about `some` method. Is it fine?

Comment: Yeah, using `some` is totally fine. `includes` just seems more semantically correct to me for the current check and makes it easier to follow. Both options are completely fine. Just avoid comparing `string` and `number` with `==` as in the accepted answer as it is generally a bad habit which will bite you someday. Convert your types manually when you compare.