# Filter Array From Another Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to filter out `contacts` from `data`. Whatever `data` gets from `contacts` should be filtered out in `remainingData`

```
contacts = [
    {
        "contact_id": 12,
        "f_name": "RARA",
    },
    {
        "contact_id": 14,
        "f_name": "BABA",
    },
    {
        "contact_id": 15,
        "f_name": "CACA",
    },
    {
        "contact_id": 14,
        "f_name": "DADA",
    },
]


data = [
    {
        "contact_id": 12,
        "f_name": "RARA",
    },
     {
        "contact_id": 14,
        "f_name": "DADA",
    },
]


remainingData = [
     {
        "contact_id": 14,
        "f_name": "BABA",
    },
    {
        "contact_id": 15,
        "f_name": "CACA",
    },
]
```

**CODE**

```
const remainingData = contacts.filter(item => item.contact_id !== data.contact_id)
```

Comment: This is the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609607/get-object-from-array-in-es6).

Comment: @Ouroborus. Its different. Its array of object vs array of objects

Comment: In what way is it different?

Comment: @Ouroborus. Previous question is array of objects vs array

Comment: There's no meaningful distinction there.

Comment: @Joseph see [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) docs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `array.filter`

```js
contacts = [
    { "contact_id": 12, "f_name": "RARA" },
    { "contact_id": 14, "f_name": "BABA" },
    { "contact_id": 15, "f_name": "CACA" },
    { "contact_id": 14, "f_name": "DADA" },
]


data = [ 
    { "contact_id": 12, "f_name": "RARA" },
    { "contact_id": 14, "f_name": "DADA" },
]

const remainingData = contacts.filter(item => !data.find((node) => item.contact_id === node.contact_id && item.f_name === node.f_name));

console.log(remainingData);
```

Alternative solution using `array.reduce`

```js
contacts = [
    { "contact_id": 12, "f_name": "RARA" },
    { "contact_id": 14, "f_name": "BABA" },
    { "contact_id": 15, "f_name": "CACA" },
    { "contact_id": 14, "f_name": "DADA" },
]


data = [ 
    { "contact_id": 12, "f_name": "RARA" },
    { "contact_id": 14, "f_name": "DADA" },
]


const remainingData = contacts.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const searchNode = data.find((node) => node.contact_id === curr.contact_id && node.f_name === curr.f_name);
    if(!searchNode) {
        acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(remainingData);
```

If you want the result of filtration back in the `contacts` variable just assign back the result of filtrarion to the same variable like

```
contacts = contacts.filter(item => !data.find((node) => item.contact_id === node.contact_id && item.f_name === node.f_name))
```

Comment: If you are performing `arrayfilter` or `array.reduce` just re assign the `contacts` variable with the response of filtration like `contacts = contacts.filter(item => !data.find((node) => item.contact_id === node.contact_id && item.f_name === node.f_name))`

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array of objects containing the ids to a normal array with only the ID's where you can check against

```js
let contacts = [{
    "contact_id": 12,
    "f_name": "RARA",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 14,
    "f_name": "BABA",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 15,
    "f_name": "CACA",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 14,
    "f_name": "DADA",
  },
]

let data = [{
    "contact_id": 12,
    "f_name": "RARA",
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 14,
    "f_name": "DADA",
  },
]

let filtered = contacts.filter(item => (data.map(x => (x.contact_id)).some(id => (id === item.contact_id))))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two objects we need to compare unique field (if exist) , so if contact_id  is unique:

```js
const remainingData = contacts.filter(item => data.find((node) => item.contact_id === node.contact_id )=='undefined');
```

Otherwise we should compare the two objects after converting them to json string , so :

```js
const remainingData = contacts.filter(item => data.find((node) => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(node))=='undefined');
```