# If all strings match in array then show matched object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I am getting back the following array below and would like to show all the matched objects based off the matched strings.

Returned Array: `["USA", "FRA", "GBR"]`

Original Array:

```
export const COUNTRY_CODES = [
  {
    country: "United States of America",
    code: "USA",
  },
  {
    country: "Albania",
    code: "ALB",
  },
  {
    country: "Algeria",
    code: "DZA",
  },
  {
    country: "France",
    code: "FRA",
  },
....
]
```

My desired Output is to show the country that matches:

```
["United States of America", "France"]
```

JS:

```
const flatArr = ["USA", "FRA", "GBR"]
COUNTRY_CODES.find((v) => flatArr === v.country)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: combined with [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to achieve this is to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const COUNTRY_CODES = [
  {
    country: "United States of America",
    code: "USA",
  },
  {
    country: "Albania",
    code: "ALB",
  },
  {
    country: "Algeria",
    code: "DZA",
  },
  {
    country: "France",
    code: "FRA",
  },
];

const flatArr = ["USA", "FRA", "GBR"];

const matchedCountries = COUNTRY_CODES.reduce((matched, countryCode) => {
  if (flatArr.includes(countryCode.code)) {
    matched.push(countryCode.country);
  }

  return matched;
}, []);

console.log(matchedCountries); // ["United States of America", "France"]
```