# How can i compare two arrays for a value and remove that value from only one of the arrays

Tags: javascript

Hi am trying to delete a specific value from arr1 if it exists in arr0, both arrays contain randomly generated numbers so the specific value may not always show in arr0.

for example,

```
const arr0 = [9, 6, 4, 3, 4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 8]; //master array
const arr1 = [2, 4, 7, 2, 9, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2]; //filtered array
```

Lets say the value i need to remove is 9, I would like arr1 to then return as,

```
const arr1 = [2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2];
```

This is to avoid duplications of a specific value shown on the website.

The random numbers are generated with the below code,

```
const arrLength = 10;
for (let i=0; i<arrLength; i++) {
    randomArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    randomArr1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: or: [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: if i am honest i don't like to hack and slash at my code as i end up completely loosing my way, im a beginner, but i have used includes(), which takes away the need to compare the master array,  and ive ran a loop through both array indexes to detect a match, this part is ok for me but i dont know how to then remove it from arr1. ive tried pop() but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @pilchard, the second link may have helped me, i need to get my head around it and try this, thanks, will keep this post open for now in case i cant get it to work and any other suggestions from anyone will be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the links but i cant see a way of implementing their solutions into my question.

Comment: I believe the reason you are receiving downvotes on your question is the question does not fully embrace the spirit of StackOverflow. We are eager to provide answers to issues that you might face, but you have to describe the specific error / failed attempt. The answers to errors we provide exist as a resource for anyone that might find the same issue, and prevent another person from needing to ask the same question. This is not explicitly a website for encouraging learning, or a free coding service. If you give a minimally reproduceable error others would be eager to help.

Comment: @aysnc await, Thankyou i didnt actually realise this and will in future aim to supply my current efforts that have not worked along with any errors i am receiving also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array) would be a great place to start for understanding how to remove an item from an array.

Arrays in javascript are a type of object. Objects are keys and values.
If you want to a function that will take this array

```js
[2, 4, 7, 2, 9, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2];
```

and return this array

```js
[2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2];
```

You are technically manipulating more than just the value `9` at key `4`. You would be reassigning a new key to each value following the space the value `9` used to be in as well.

If you are trying to return an array that is filtered based on certain criteria, such as the number being 9, you could use the method `.filter` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

A brief overview of `.filter`, the method has optional arguments and functionality that is beyond the scope of a brief overview, but to keep things short; the `.filter` method takes a callback function as an argument. The callback function will be applied to each item in the array, with the item being passed as an argument. If the function returns true, the item will be returned in the result. If the function returns false, the item will not be returned in the result.

i.e.

```js
console.log(
  [2, 4, 7, 2, 9, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2]
    .filter(number => number !== 9)
    .toString()
);
```

```css
/*styling console display -- not relevant to answer*/
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I used an anonymous arrow function as my callback function, `number => number !== 9`, this is the equivalent of

```js
function (number) {
  return number !== 9
}
```

What happens is each item in the array is passed as an argument to my callback function. I am declaring the name of the variable where that argument will be passed is called `number`. I am returning `number !== 9` which will return `true` so long as the number is not 9. This means each item will be checked to see if it is equal to 9, and if it is not, it will return true, making the final array returned filter out all values equal to 9. I will give you an example of another filter statement.

```js
[2, 4, 7, 2, 9, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2].filter(
  function( anyName ) {
    if ( anyName === 9 ) return false;
    if ( anyName === 3 ) return false;
    if (anyName / 2 === 2) return false;
    return true;
  }
);
//returns [2, 7, 2, 0, 6, 2]
```

this filter returns false when an item is 9, 3, or when divided by 2 is 2 (i.e. 4)

The first example would however remove all instances of the value 9 in the array. If you only want to remove the first occurring 9 you could do this several ways.

You could use `.findIndex` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex))  and remove the value by it's index.

i.e.

```js
const arr1 = [2, 4, 7, 2, 9, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2];
const indexToRemove = arr1.findIndex(number => number === 9);
const processedArr = [
  ...arr1.slice(0, indexToRemove),
  ...arr1.slice(indexToRemove + 1, arr1.length)
];
console.log(processedArr.toString());
```

```css
/*styling console display -- not relevant to answer*/
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

hopefully this helps point you in the right direction- if you have more specific examples of your goal please update your question

Comment: thanks!!! this is exactly what i need, i was looking at filter() earlier but i currently don't understand too well what exactly is going on within that line of code  .filter(number => number !== 9). to me it looks like you are comparing number that is either equal or more to number that is not equals  to 9... cant quite get my head around that.

Comment: @nezza1 I added an edit to give an overview of the `.filter` method, let me know if have any more questions! I used what's called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)