# how to filter based on two values from the array of array

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch array of objects with participants and messages, I want to filter the  object with the below array of two participants, can anyone help with this

this is the example participnats of array :

`["61badffe4ccf060b329441e0","61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"]`

bunch of sample messages and participants :

````
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61bae01b4ccf060b329441ef"
    ],
    "_id": "61bae0394ccf060b329441fb",
  },
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61bae1014ccf060b3294420e",
      "61bae01b4ccf060b329441ef"
    ],
    "_id": "61bb230c4ccf060b3294421c"
  },
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"
    ],
    "_id": "61d476dff651471663a72971",
  },
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61e54b82eab592e7fef65656"
    ],
    "_id": "61e54ba3eab592e7fef6567a",
]





**expected below object after filter participants:** 

```{
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"
    ],
    "_id": "61d476dff651471663a72971",
  },
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna use `Array.filter()` and also in your case you should check every element from that array which should match your criteria.

```js
const input = [{
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61bae01b4ccf060b329441ef"
    ],
    "_id": "61bae0394ccf060b329441fb",
  },
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61bae1014ccf060b3294420e",
      "61bae01b4ccf060b329441ef"
    ],
    "_id": "61bb230c4ccf060b3294421c"
  },
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"
    ],
    "_id": "61d476dff651471663a72971",
  },
  {
    "messages": [],
    "participants": [
      "61badffe4ccf060b329441e0",
      "61e54b82eab592e7fef65656"
    ],
    "_id": "61e54ba3eab592e7fef6567a",
    }
];

const filterByParticipants = ["61badffe4ccf060b329441e0","61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"];
const output = input.filter(el => el.participants.every(el => filterByParticipants.includes(el)));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of Array Object, to filter it based on certain conditions.
You can then use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method of `participants` array, to check if every participant is present in the object.

```js
let obj=[{messages:[],participants:["61badffe4ccf060b329441e0","61bae01b4ccf060b329441ef"],_id:"61bae0394ccf060b329441fb"},{messages:[],participants:["61bae1014ccf060b3294420e","61bae01b4ccf060b329441ef"],_id:"61bb230c4ccf060b3294421c"},{messages:[],participants:["61badffe4ccf060b329441e0","61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"],_id:"61d476dff651471663a72971"},{messages:[],participants:["61badffe4ccf060b329441e0","61e54b82eab592e7fef65656"],_id:"61e54ba3eab592e7fef6567a"}];

let participants =["61badffe4ccf060b329441e0","61bc33a84ccf060b32944354"];

let res = obj.filter((o)=>{
  let oParticipants = o.participants;
  let out = participants.every(p => oParticipants.includes(p))
  return out;
});

console.log(res)
```